# Sum of elements of two integer array in a single string array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, sum

Have a function Arr(strArr) read the array of strings stored in strArr which will contain only two elements, both of which will represent an array of positive integers. For example of strArr is ["[1, 2, 5, 6]", "[5, 2, 8, 11]"], and goal for this is to add the elements in corresponding locations from both arrays. For the example input, the program should do the following additions: [(1 + 5), (2 + 2), (5 + 8), (6 + 11)] which then equals [6, 4, 13, 17]. Return this resulting array in a string format with each element separated by a hyphen: 6-4-13-17.

If the two arrays do not have the same amount of elements, then simply append the remaining elements onto the new array.

Examples

```
Input: ["[5, 2, 3]", "[2, 2, 3, 10, 6]"]
Output: 7-4-6-10-6
```

```
Input: ["[1, 2, 1]", "[2, 1, 5, 2]"]
Output: 3-3-6-2
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework. We'll help you with any problems you experience _when you try it yourself_. See https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: It's not homework. Its coderbyte challange.

Comment: That's a distinction without a difference. If we give you the answer, it defeats the learning value of the exercise. In any case, "do my work for me" (for whatever kind of work: homework, learning exercises, or professional tasks from a day job) aren't well received here, because they don't show any initiative or background work on the part of the poster. Worse yet, this site isn't a free software consultancy. The whole point of this site is to build up a repository of questions/answers that have lasting value for future readers. "How to solve this one-off problem" has low future value.

Comment: That said, if you show your attempt to solve the problem, and a concrete description of where you got stuck or what went wrong, the people here would be _more than happy_ to help you get unstuck and figure out your *specific programming problem*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems obviously a homework exercise, and as was pointed out in comments that's not what StackOverflow is for; however, I know a lot of students who struggle to know even how to approach a problem.  I think helping with that is a good thing, so I won't give a solution to the problem, but rather advice about approaching it.

The general formula that works for most problems is simple: Break the problem into smaller sub-problems, and solve each of those independently, then combine the sub-solutions.  If any of those sub-problems are too complicated, repeat the process for those, and so on.

Homework problems, and a lot of real world problems, usually break down into three main sub-problems:

1. Transform some input into a more conveniently computable form.
2. Process the transformed input into some computed outputs.
3. Transform the computed outputs into a specified format.

Applied to your problem, you have:

1. How to parse a specially formatted string into an array of integers.
2. How to sum corresponding elements of two arrays, taking into account they may be of different lengths, to produce an array of sums.
3. How to transform an array of integers into a specially delimited string output.

The solution to your top-level problem will involve applying the sub-solutions in that order, but you don't have to solve them in that order.  If you're having difficulty with getting started with the first one, solve one of the easier sub-solutions first to get some momentum.  Psychology is actually quite important in problem solving.  Believing you can solve it is half of actually solving it, so solve the easier problems first to get that factor working in your favor.

Maybe you regard the sub-problem 3 as the easiest to solve: So write a function place-holder for it (aka, a "stub function"), and make up some input data to test it.  This would lead you to write something like this:

```swift
func formatOutput(from intArray: [Int]) -> String
{
    // Your implementation will go here
}

let actual = formatOutput(from: [1, 2, 3, 4])
let expected = "1-2-3-4"

// If you're doing this in a playground, app, or command line tool 
if actual != expected { 
    fatalError("FAILED: \"\(actual)\" != \"\(expected)\"")
}
else { print("Yay! Passed!") }

// If you're using XCTest
XCTAssertEqual(actual, expected)
```

That won't even compile yet, because `formatOutput` has to return something, and it doesn't yet. The key thing is that you've written your usage code first, and expressed *in code* what you expect.  Now focus on the guts of `formatOutput`.  If you want to take a Test Driven Development approach (TDD), maybe at first just return an empty string from `formatOutput` so you can be sure the code compiles and you see a failing test.  Then implement it correctly if you know how, or in small steps if you're not clear on what to do.  As you get the exact thing you're testing for working, you can keep adding more tests and improving `formatOutput` until you've verifiably got it doing everything it's supposed to do.  Remember the KISS principle: "Keep It Simple, Stupid!"  Don't over-think the solution, and save doing it "cleverly" for another day, which often never comes because the simple thing was sufficient.

At that point you have one of the sub-problems solved, so you move on to the next, following the same pattern.  And the next, until all the parts are solved.  Then put them together.

You'll note that sub-problem 2 has a bit of an extended description, especially the part specifying that the arrays may be of different lengths.  Unless you already know how to solve that problem as stated, that sort of thing indicates it's a good candidate to be broken into yet simpler problems:

- 2a. How to sum corresponding elements of two arrays of the same length.
- 2b. How to modify 2a to handle arrays of different lengths.

2b can be done a few different ways:

- 2.b.1. Apply 2.a to sub-arrays of common length, then handle the remaining part of the longer one separately

OR

- 2.b.2. Enlarge the shorter array so that it is the same length as the longer one, so 2.a can be applied unmodified.

OR

- 2.b.3. Modify 2.a so that it can treat the shorter array as though it were the same length as the longer one, without actually copying or adding new elements.

OR

- 2.b.4. Modify 2.a so that it doesn't have to do anything special for different lengths at all. Hint: think more about the output and its length than the inputs.

When faced with alternatives like that, in the absence of any external constraints that would make one option preferred over the others, pick the one that seems simplest to you (or the most interesting, or the one you think you'd learn the most from).  Or if you have time, and want to get the most out of the exercise, implement all of them so you can learn how they are all done, and then pick the one you like best for your final code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I am sorry for your prejudice because it is not homework. It is just coderbyte challenge on which I am stuck. I really tried hard to get the answer. I decided to ask StackOverflow, and your response is really depressing. I hope one day you will stop being judgemental.

Comment: I'm sorry you found it depressing, and I do apologize if its not a homework assignment, but it is framed exactly, and I do mean exactly, like homework.  And how is a coderbyte challenge any different?  I mean its purpose is still to learn right.  Next time I suggest you add to your question what you tried to do, so we can help you with that.  It's more useful for you and more respectful of the time people on SO spend trying to help others.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm new at stackoverflow. Your response is valuable by the way. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @HikmetUygur I'm sorry to hear that's how you interpreted this response, because Jarred put some pretty substantial effort into providing this insightful, detailed and _generalizable_ answer to not just this question, but most other ones like this. If you're just looking for someone to give you a blob to copy-paste into Coderbyte to make a green check mark pop up, I would ask: 1) Why would you actually want that? What value is it to you? 2) Why would someone would want to volunteer to do that for you, for free?

Comment: @Alexander I actually found depressing for prejudice. I didn't find it a depressing response. Try to understand what I write and react to that. If you actually read what I said about his response you will understand I hope.

Comment: @HikmetUygur could you please clarify what prejudice you’re perceiving? This might not be the case here, but I’ll point out that sometimes people ask a “newbie” question and think that the negative response is because the question was newbie. 9 times out of 10, it’s not; we’ll written questions about simple topics/problems are some of the highest rated questions. Instead, it usually comes down to the _quality_ of the simple question. Adding your background research, showing what you tried, etc. will give people a sense that you at least put in effort, and they’ll be happy to assist fromthere

Comment: For what it's worth, I took @HikmetUygur's use of "prejudice" to be the literal meaning of the word, an *a priori* judgement about something, specifically that I judged question as homework based on its appearance.  And that's totally true.  I did judge the question based only on its exactly following that pattern along with the frequency such questions are posted without asking for clarification.  If instead any of the socially charged specific meanings it often has these days was intended, it would be unworthy of response.

Comment: @Alexander BTW, thank you for your kind words about my answer.  Like a lot of general advice, it's tricky to bridge the gap between being so general that it's not actionable and being so specific that it's only about one particular problem. Yet bridging the gap is necessary.  Telling a person who is suffering from depression, for example, that "happiness comes from within" is useless.  It's true, but contains no information about exactly how one can apply it.  Same with breaking problems into simpler ones. Thank you for seeing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
func getResult(strArr: [String]) -> String {
    let intArray1 = (try? JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: Data(strArr[0].utf8))) ?? []
    let intArray2 = (try? JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: Data(strArr[1].utf8))) ?? []
    var arrayResult = zip(intArray1,intArray2).map(+)
    let commonCount = arrayResult.count
    arrayResult.append(contentsOf: intArray1.dropFirst(commonCount))
    arrayResult.append(contentsOf: intArray2.dropFirst(commonCount))
    return arrayResult.map(String.init).joined(separator: "-")
}

let result1 = getResult(strArr : ["[5, 2, 3]", "[2, 2, 3, 10, 6]"])
let result2 = getResult(strArr : ["[1, 2, 1]", "[2, 1, 5, 2]"])
```

You can use this function to get your desired result.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. The strings are a valid json format. You can simply `decode([Int].self, from: Data(string.utf8))`. Btw `.map() {$0 + $1}` can be simplified as `.map(+)`

Comment: @LeoDabus, given that the question seems to be a homework exercise, I suspect the whole point is to learn "how wheels work" making an exception to the  "don't reinvent the wheel" maxim.  Q) When should you write you own sort? A) When you're learning how sorting works.  For similar reasons, I would think that `JSONDecoder` as well as `.map`, `.filter`, `.joined`, etc... are all likely inappropriate in this specific context.  In a professional context, sure... all those are appropriate and encouraged - except `JSONDecoder` is very slow and overkill.